# Check if the value is null and assign it 0

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making an app for the mobile that is a calculator.If you do not put any number and days to calculate it will crash.I think it is because the value is null, and it cannot be operated on.

How can I check if it is null and if so, assign it the value 0.

```
editTextnum1= findViewById(R.id.editTextnum1);

String num1= editTextnum1.getText().toString();

int Inum1= Integer.parseInt(num1);
```

With the variable Inum1 I do the operation in calculator.
Any ideas or help on how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to check a condition and set the value like 0

```
String num1 = editTextnum1.getText().toString();
num1 = num1.isEmpty() ? "0" : num1;
```

Comment: Oh ya i forgot! I get used to called it elvis because I use Kotlin. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: how to use in kotlin?

Comment: @Mohan kotlin doesnt have ternary operator, it uses if else instead. `num1 = if(num1.isEmpty()) "0" else num1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be designing your code block like below to avoid null exceptions :

```
editTextnum1= findViewById(R.id.editTextnum1);
if(editTextnum1 == null){
    log.info("View not found for id : " + R.id.editTextnum1);
    // do something or return from here
} else {
    log.info("View found for id : " + R.id.editTextnum1);
    String num1= editTextnum1.getText().toString();
    if (null == num1) {
        // do something or return from here
    } else {
        int Inum1= Integer.parseInt(num1);
        // do something.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the value of `num1` like this.

```java
if (num1 == null || or num1.isEmpty()) {
    // no input; do something!
} else {
    int Inum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    // happily do your job.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if editTextnum1 is null or empty

```
int Inum1 = editTextnum1.isEmpty() || editTextnum1 == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num1);
```